# is there any way for me to log in to minecraft with no email?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have forgotten the email I signed up with but am still logged in to my account, however this is an old pc and I just got a new one but I just cant log in, is there any way for me to get back in to this account?

Comment: You will need to contact mojang support to recover your login information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *legal* way to log in without the account info, and sorry, Arquade doesn't give advice on how to violate EULAs.

Instead, find the file `launcher_accounts.json` in the `.minecraft` folder (on Windows it's `%AppData%\Roaming\.minecraft` ) on your old computer, and among other info you'll find your old email address in there. You may even try copying the file to your new computer.

If besides forgetting the email address you forgot the password, you'll need to contact Mojang support. (also, the purchase ID from the email you have received when buying the game would be an alternative credentials for the support contact).

Comment: Just to clarify, if you get the email address but forgot the password obviously just go to the login site and click "Forgot Password"

Comment: @Penguin: At that point the site asks "verification questions". NOBODY ever remembers answers to these.

Comment: that's not what happens for me. For me it just says "enter your email" and then it will send a password reset

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't because you have three methods of login.
Login with

- Microsoft Account
- Xbox Live Account
- Mojang Account

Every one of these requires a Email adress.

Comment: This is not exactly accurate. While yes, the login methods all do require an email address, this information is recoverable by contacting Mojang

Comment: Oh Ok, Good to know! Thanks for telling me! Though I believe that he wrote soemthing else.. like in "Is there a Way to log into my Minecraft Account without an Email Address?". Mandela effect kicked in. Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure you can login with Xbox Live? Also by "Java Account" I think you might mean "Mojang Account"

Comment: Well yes, that is right.

Comment: Not trying to sound picky, but I just changed it because of the migration thing making accounts now confusing